# Merging CAB install files into two

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, cab

To prepare an installation for Windows Mobile I would like to know if the practice is legal:

1. I have my own CAB installer
2. I have CAB .NET Compact Framework installer
3. I merge them into one final CAB as my own installer

What if I merge _setup.xml files from those two CABs and add files from them into one final CAB. Would it be right to have installed my own application together with .NET CF? It worked but is it legal or not?

By the way I am looking for a job as .NET developer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm no lawyer, so don't accept this as "legal advice."

Since the .NET Compact Framework itself is redistributable, I don't see any problem with packaging it with your own application for distribution.  In fact we've done it in the past.